# Can I print the manual since I can't follow the online tutorials as the type is so small I am 89!

Tags: documentation

Blender looks like a great program, but the online tutorials even with windows magnification the text is too small to read and at the same time work on a project - with only one monitor available.  I am 89!
The main thing I want is type fonts and I could not find any in the program.  So can I download AND print out the manual? Any suggestions to both the "problems" would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I am 59 and have poor eyesight so I can relate. First, try using the keyboard combination crtl and the plus key(+) and minus key(-) to enlarge and shrink the manual or any web page for that matter in order to read the text more easily. This works on the firefox and google chrome browser for sure as I just tested it out. You can also download the manual as a zip file to read it off-line from here https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/. It's still in HTML format so it will open from from your hard drive into your web browser program. I just downloaded the manual myself and it displays just fine in Firefox(my default web browser). If you are using Windows 10 there is also a magnifying glass feature you can use. Google "magnifying text in windows" to learn how to use it. If you really really want to print out the manual you can convert the on-line HTML manual to PDF by using this free service https://www.win2pdf.com/html-to-pdf.html or you can buy the win2pdf program for $35 to convert and print from your down loaded manual. Hope this helps you out.

Regards, Jeff.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** Since Blender 2.92 the manual is also available as ePUB, which means that building it yourself is no longer necessary. The download link is on the [front page of the manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/index.html). You may have to install additional software to open ePUB files though, for instance Adobe Digital Editions or Sumatra PDF.

---

Unfortunately the .pdf building for the Blender manual with Sphinx and LaTeX is currently a bit fragile. The generation of the table of contents doesn't work properly and there may be formatting issues. The instructions for building the manual yourself can be found in the [*Contribute*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/about/contribute/index.html#contribute)  chapter. `make pdf` is the command to create the .pdf version.

The HTML version for offline use can be downloaded on the [front page of the reference manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/index.html).

---

> The main thing I want is type fonts and I could not find any in the program.

Creating text objects in Blender is possible through *Add > Text*.

[image: Add Text]

The font can be selected in the *Object Data* properties of the text object.

[image: Choose Font]

Comment: You sir, deserve a medal! :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking a look at [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) - you can download the zipped html document and then convert it to epub, (to view on an e-reader), or PDF or any of a number of other formats. *(Note that a hard copy printout will consume a lot of paper & toner/ink it **might** be cheaper to buy a book).*

Comment: The full manual is 2183 pages long. Therefore, I agree that this will require a lot of paper and ink.